# migration of jboss 4.2 to wildfly 8

Tags: java, xml, jboss, wildfly

we have legacy java project with ear deployment structure.

```
.ear---| classes
      | lib
      | META-INF ---| application.xml
      | .war               | jboss-app.xml
                              | MENIFEST.MF
```

which is running fine on jboss 4.2.  now we are migrating jboss 4.2 to wildfly 8. 
ERROR : jboss-app.xml is deprecated and "loader-repository" is ignored.
we gone through the  wildfly document then we came to know that we have to create  jboss-deployment-structure.xml to define modules.

we have  jboss-app.xml:-

```
 <jboss-app>
  <module-order>strict</module-order>
  <loader-repository>
  com.mono.myproject:archive=CompleteApp.ear
  <loader-repository-config> 
      java2ParentDelegation=false 
      </loader-repository-config>
  </loader-repository>
  <library-directory>/lib</library-directory>
  <module>
  <web>
  <web-uri>firstWeb.war</web-uri>
  <context-root>firstWeb</context-root>
  </web>
  </module>


  <module>
  <web>
  <web-uri>secondWeb.war</web-uri>
  <context-root>secondWeb</context-root>
  </web>
  </module>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>thirdWeb.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>thirdWeb</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
 </jboss-app>
```

1. How can we load above (loader-repository) in jboss-deployment-structure.xml in wildfly 8?
2. Without loader repository we have tried but got ERROR:- linkage error (com.mono.myproject not found)

Thanks in advance.